# He [Climbed / Climbed up] a tree

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> He [Climbed / Climbed up] a tree

Does using climb or climb up in the above sentence makes any difference ? I think the only difference is while using the latter one one is specifying the direction i.e. He is going *up* on the tree e.g. If it was He climbed down the tree one mean to say he came *down* from the tree, but while using former one (just *climbed* instead of *climbed up* )it is not explicit but implicit that he is going up on the tree. Is there any other difference than this ? Or is it incorrect to use *climb* without *up/down* ?

Answer (score 1):

With simple past **climbed**, **up** isn't *purely* directional but can also convey the idea of having reached a place in the tree, the top or whatever height in the tree the climber was going for.

There is no requirement to use **up** with **climb**.

Answer (score 0):

I think `climbed up the tree` is not wrong.

`He climbed the tree`may mean He climbed up the tree.

`He climbed down the tree`is the opposite of ```climbed up the tree``